# Conditional selection in FROM clause

Tags: postgresql, case, condition

I have two tables:

- `parent` with columns `identifier` (pkey) and `period`;
- `child` with columns `identifier` (pkey), `parent_identifier` and `period`.

There are additional columns, but I did not list them here as they are not really relevant.

I want to select the periods as following:

- If the `parent` matches some predicate, then pick `parent.period`.
- If not, then pick `child.period` from each child.

I have the following query:

```
select   q.period
from     parent,
lateral  (
           select  parent.period
           where   <some complex predicate>
           union all
           select  child.period
           from    child
           where   child.parent_identifier = parent.identifier and
                   not(<the same complex predicate as above>)
         ) as q(period);
```

While this query works and returns the expected periods, I am wondering if this query could be rewritten in such way that `<some complex predicate>` does not have to be evaluated twice, to improve performance (albeit by a small factor) and general query structure to represent the `if ... else ...` from above. Ideally, I want to loop once through each `parent`/`child` row and evaluate the predicate just once.

I tried to introduce a `case when <some complex predicate> then ... else ... end` clause, but I fail to get it right. I am not sure if that is even possible in the `FROM` clause. Is this possible?

I also had `select case when <predicate> then parent.period else unnest(array(select child.period from child where ...)) from parent` in mind (though I did not try it, so it might be disallowed in a `case when ...` as well), but I am not sure if first creating and then unnesting an array is really optimal. Also, I am not really fond of set-returning functions, such as `unnest`, in the selection.

Comment: Do you need more than one row or one column from child, per row of parent?

Comment: @jjanes A parent can have multiple children, so I want to have the period columns of all those children, as demonstrated in the query. I do not need to have other child properties, besides the period column. Do you have something like `SELECT CASE WHEN <predicate> THEN parent.period ELSE unnest(array(SELECT child.period FROM child WHERE ...)) FROM parent` in mind?

Comment: that is more or less what I had in mind, although I think the unnest would have to go into an outer select wrapped around the one with the array_agg.  (Or return the array_agg to the client and have the client deal with it).  I can't think of an option that will meet your preferences better than you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following queries evaluate the expensive predicate just once for each `parent` row. To achieve this, the predicate is evaluated in a separate subquery. The first version uses a lateral join, the second an inner join. This meets the requirements from the question.

```
select   q2.period
from     parent,
lateral  (
           select <some complex predicate>
         ) as q1(predicate),
lateral  (
           select  parent.period
           where   q1.predicate
           union all
           select  child.period
           from    child
           where   child.parent_identifier = parent.identifier and
                   not(q1.predicate)
         ) as q2(period);
```

```
select     q2.period
from       parent,
inner join (
             select  parent.identifier, <some complex predicate>
             from    parent
           ) as q1(identifier, predicate)
on         parent.identifier = q1.identifier,
lateral    (
             select  parent.period
             where   q1.predicate
             union all
             select  child.period
             from    child
             where   child.parent_identifier = parent.identifier and
                     not(q1.predicate)
           ) as q2(period);
```